# What package (helper app) does recoll need to index images?

Tags: package-management, system

The `File->Show_missing_helpers` menu item in the recoll GUI mentions the following missing helper (among others):

```
Perl::Image::ExifTool (image/gif image/jpeg image/png image/tiff image/x-xcf)
```

Per the recoll user manual I installed the perl image exif tool (and library):

```
sudo aptitude install libimage-exif-perl libimage-exiftool-perl
```

but recoll still lists the missing helper and fails to index images.

`uname -a`:

```
Linux AlSSD 3.2.0-30-generic #48-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 24 16:52:48 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that only libimage-exiftool-perl is needed, but the other one should not be a problem.

What recoll version are you using ?

Did you try to execute exiftool on the command line that the installation is ok (exiftool myfile.jpg) ?

Did you try to restart the GUI and/or the indexing after installing exiftool ?

If this does not help, we need to take a look at the recoll log file: see for example https://bitbucket.org/medoc/recoll/wiki/WhyIsMyFileNotIndexed.wiki about how to do this.

Hopefully the error will be obvious in the log.

Comment: Yea, exiftool *.jpg works fine (prints out the exif tags).

Comment: Version: Recoll 1.17.3 + Xapian 1.2.8.

Comment: Now recoll EXIF indexing is working :). Since the time it wasn't working, I've installed all the other missing helpers (`sudo apt-get install catdoc perl-image-exiftool pstotext python-chm python-mutagen unrtf`), rebooted, updated the index and let it run to completion, rebooted a couple more times. I rebooted after installing just perl-image-exiftool and rebooted before posting this question. So reboot wasn't it. Perhaps exercising recoll GUI with the update index refreshed its parsing of the conf file, etc. Or maybe one of the other helpers helped.

Answer (score 2):

The solution for Ubuntu 15:04:

[image]

```
$ sudo apt-get install libimage-exiftool-perl antiword python-mutagen python-rarfile untex
```

Comment: Does this mean recoll can scan through image text? Or what is the purpose of indexing images? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A) Install libimage-exiftool-perl

B) In Recoll, File - Update Index.

Two pitfalls:

1. File - Show missing helpers will only show the *first* helper
   that was *actually needed but not found when the index was last updated*. It will NOT show all currently missing helpers! (Recoll 1.16.2).
2. Missing helpers will cause Recoll (1.16.2) to silently abort indexing.

---

Frequently used helper packages in Ubuntu/Xubuntu are: xsltproc (for OpenOffice), poppler-utils (for pdf), catdoc (for Excel/Powerpoint), antiword (for Word), libimage-exiftool-perl (for images, including embedded ones apparently)

Comment: Yea, I can confirm that your "pitfalls" were what held me up.